# mod_rewrite URL change with additional parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Struggling to get anything but simple rewrites to happen so I am hoping I can present a real example and get a sample so I can understand what I am doing wrong.

This is the existing URL:

- http://127.0.0.1/reports/queue.php?status=all&frequency=all

Trying to change it to:

- http://127.0.0.1/api/server/server.php?f=ReportQueue&selector=queue&status=all&frequency=all

What is interesting is I cant even "break" it to step through and see how my changes impact the rewrite. For example I would do:

```bash
RewriteRule ^reports/queue(.*)$ api/server/server.php$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

I actually expected this to provide a page not found but it doesn't seem to do anything. I have verified that mod_rewrite is working by doing some more simple examples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't notice that difference. Was not trying to change that. I updated the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /reports/queue\.php\?status=all&frequency=all [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /api/server/server.php?f=ReportQueue&selector=queue [L,QSA,R=302]
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit to reflect edited question

Comment: This didnt change anything . Also wouldnt the request have to have those exact parameters? They can change as parameters often do.

Comment: If you want URL to change then use `RewriteRule ^ /api/server/server.php?f=ReportQueue&selector=queue [L,QSA,R=302]`